# GGPlot-Facet Bar Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm strugling with an assignment which asks us the following:

we have two data set with questions ID as observation and answer as variable, for 2 groups

```
First set
   True False
Q1  30    20
Q2  25    25

Second set set
   True False
Q1  30    20
Q2  25    25
```

it is asked that i produce a facet chart with gg plot that put the side by side charts answer of one group versus the other for each questions, so on each question you have a chart with one bar per type of answer  with both groups having different colors.

Truth is, i have no idea how to do that eventhough i looked through the documentation, i find GGplot really messy :O

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a `tidyverse` approach using `ggplot2` as mentioned. First you must have data in next structure (I add the `dput()` version to make the example reproducible):

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(True = c(30L, 25L, 30L, 25L), False = c(20L, 25L, 
20L, 25L), Group = c("Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 2"
), Question = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q1", "Q2")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

You can use `rbind()` or `bind_rows()` from `dplyr` to bind the data you included. Then, is necessary to difference the groups as next:

```
  True False   Group Question
1   30    20 Group 1       Q1
2   25    25 Group 1       Q2
3   30    20 Group 2       Q1
4   25    25 Group 2       Q2
```

With this you can sketch the plot with this code reshaping the data and including your desired elements in the plot as bars (`geom_bar()`) and you can facet or split by some variable with `facet_wrap()`:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(Group,Question)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Group,y=value,fill=Question))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge())+
  facet_wrap(.~name)
```

Output:

[image]